# IOS8 VPN Extension on demand connection

Tags: objective-c, ios8, vpn

I'm trying to create an on-demand rule NEVPNManager object. The rule is simple -  once a connection to a given ip/host will be established start the VPN connection.

The following code just starts the VPN for every http request, more so it can't be disabled. When changing the host to and ip nothing happens.

```
NEOnDemandRuleConnect *connectRule = [NEOnDemandRuleConnect new];
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents new];
components.scheme = @"http";
components.host = @"yahoo.com";
NSURL *url = [components URL];
connectRule.probeURL = url1;
```

Ideally I'll be able to start the VPN for every type of communication.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of iOS app extension are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm using NEVPNManager

Comment: `NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect` doesn't seem to disconnect.  have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another rule but use `NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect`.